# Сравнение чисел в массиве Java. Некорректно сравнивает отрицательные числа

Tags: java, массивы, алгоритм

1. Нужно сравнить числа в массиве и вывести на экран самое большое. Код это делает.
2. Проблема: некорректно сравниваются отрицательные числа. Не пойму почему.
3. Если максимальных чисел несколько, нужно вывести на экран.

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {    
        InputStream inputStream = System.in;
        Reader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

        int [] array = new int[4];
        int max = 0;
        int eq = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            array[i] = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (Math.abs(array[i]) > max){
                max = array[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(max);
    }
```

Comment: Поинтересуйтесь, что делает функция `Math.abs`...

Comment: Что значит "некорректно сравниваются отрицательные числа"? Приведите пример некорректности

Answer (score 2):

Проблема заключается в этом блоке кода

```
        if (Math.abs(array[i]) > max){
            max = array[i];
        }
```

Вы сравниваете абсолютную величину элемента `array[i]` с не абсолютной величиной переменной `max`. Я предполагаю, что вы ищите в массиве элемент по максимальному абсолютному значению. Иначе, вообще, не понятно, почему вы используете метод `abs`.

По крайней мере вам следовало бы написать

```
        if (Math.abs(array[i]) > Math.abs( max ) ){
            max = array[i];
        }
```

Кроме того данный алгоритм обычно выполняется следующим образом.
Сначала `max` кладется равной значению `array[0]`. Затем используете цикл, начиная со счетчика цикла, равного 1.

Вот минимальная демонстрационная программа, которая показывает, как найти максимум по абсолютной величине и просто максимум.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int[] array = { -100 , -5, 80, 999, 666, -3333 };

        int max_abs = array[0];
        int max = array[0];

        for ( int i = 1; i < array.length; i++ )
        {
            if ( Math.abs( max_abs ) < Math.abs( array[i] ) )
            {
                max_abs = array[i];
            }

            if ( max < array[i] )
            {
                max = array[i];
            }
        }

        System.out.println( "Absolute maximum value is " + Math.abs( max_abs ) );
        System.out.println( "Maximum value is " + max );
    }
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
Absolute maximum value is 3333
Maximum value is 999
```

Сравните полученные результаты.

Что касается данного пункта

> 3.Если максимальных чисел несколько, нужно вывести на экран.

то следует поместить его в отдельный вопрос. То есть в одном вопросе разберитесь с отрицательными числами, а в другом вопросе решайте уже совершенно другую проблему, предоставив соответствующий код, и указав, что у вас не получается. Скорей всего вам потребуется использовать `ArrayList` для этих целей.

Comment: и среди массива  -100  , -5 ,80,99999,666,-3333 самое большое будет -3333....

Comment: @MaxKrugovykh Все правильно, так как ищется абсолютное максимальное значение, как это следует из авторского кода.

Comment: Т/З 1.Нужно сравнить числа в массиве и вывести на экран самое большое.

Comment: *как это следует из авторского кода* Но это НЕ следует из текста задания. Автор, вероятно, просто скопировал чужое решение другой задачи. И теперь старается подрихтовать его для себя.

Comment: @Akina Тут трудно разобраться, какое на самом деле было задание. Я смотрю код, а не на то, что, порой, начинающие программисты не могут корректно продублировать задание.

Comment: Думаю, тот, кто написал приведённый код, способен скопировать текст задания в вопрос... хотя студенты - да, они такие.

Comment: Код сделан по образу и подобию. Более того везде решения задачи используют scanner и кучу сравнений, через массив показалось удобнее. На грабли наступил на отрицательных числах и прошу помощи с этим.

Comment: @k-paxian Вам про abs(), а вы почему-то про массив и сканнер...

Comment: Разобрался. Очень тупо было инитить max ДО введения чисел в массив, потому max получал (null) и начиналась туфта.

Comment: Интересно, откуда получался `null` в массиве примитивных интов..

Answer (score 0):

По ваше логике вы сравниваете модуль числа с числом, что не есть хорошо. присвойте переменной max значение **array[0];**  и в сравнении начиная от **i=1**, сравнивайте элементы

**PS.** При присвоении 0 элементу значения  первого Элемента массива , вы решите проблему с отрицательными числами

Comment: В этом коде - не решит.

Comment: я про этот код и не говорю,  а про то что написал я. Ибо он для обхода отрицательных зачем-то юзал abs

Comment: Так а как нужно сделать?

Comment: @k-paxian  изменить код:  int max = array[0];  и  for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
            if (array[i] > max){
                max = array[i];
            }
    }

Comment: @k-paxian Остальное правильно более менее

Comment: @MaxKrugovykh Благодарю, уже решил. у меня int max = array [0] проиничено ДО ввода значений в массив. Из-за этого и началась чехарда с Math.abs, которое тут вообще не при чем.